# Trying to use XML returned by merriam webster dictionary API but request getting failed. Status returned is zero. What to do?

Tags: javascript, xml, dictionary, xmlhttprequest

I saw this great API (http://www.dictionaryapi.com/products/api-collegiate-dictionary.htm) by merriam webster that returns an XML file with all the details in it including definitions and pronunciations.
This API requires a key so i registered and got a key for my account.
I am making the request using Javascript(XHR) but the status returned is zero.
Then i googled the error it said that it may be because my request is going from a "file:///" protocol instead of "http://", so i installed LAMP stack on my PC then hosted the file on my localhost server and even then no luck.
Another thread said that i cant make cross domain requests.
Please can you help me. Below is my HTML code from which i call function in my javascript file.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="context-script.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Merriam Webster</h1>
  <div>
    <b>To:</b> <span id="to"></span><br />
    <b>From:</b> <span id="from"></span><br />
    <b>Message:</b> <span id="message"></span><br/>
    <b>Sound:</b><span id="sound"></span><br />
  </div>
<script>
   callOtherDomain();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my JAvascript file context-script.js code:

```
function callOtherDomain() 
{
    invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/collegiate/xml/happy?key=8f394b2c-77e8-433d-b599-f3ca87660067';
    //url="note.xml";
    if(invocation) 
    {    
        invocation.open('GET', url, true);
        invocation.withCredentials = "true";
        invocation.onreadystatechange = handler;
        invocation.send(); 
        alert("ref");
    }
 }
 function handler(evtXHR)
 {
      if (invocation.readyState == 4)
      {
          alert("erg");
          if (invocation.status == 200)
          {
              var response = invocation.responseXML;
              document.getElementById("to").innerHTML=
              response.getElementsByTagName("dt")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
              document.getElementById("from").innerHTML=
              response.getElementsByTagName("dt")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
              document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=
              response.getElementsByTagName("dt")[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue;    
            }
            else
                 alert(invocation.status);
    }
    else
        dump("currently the application is at" + invocation.readyState);
}
```

But when i change the URL to "note.xml" which is locally stored on the localhost code works absolutely fine.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need cors to use an xml api from JS

Comment: @dandavis  could you please elaborate it some more , it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

While this question is several years old, I worked with [dictionaryapi.com](http://www.dictionaryapi.com) previously and the solution is two-fold:

1. Your first step to host on a local server was right on (`localhost:8000` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000`). I prefer using the Python SimpleHTTPServer, started in the root directory of the page you're trying to host with whichever CLI tool you're most familiar/comfortable with, `py -m http.server`.
2. After that, just complete a jQuery call using `ajax`, `get`, or `XMLHttpRequest`—whichever you prefer. For example:

   ```
   $.ajax({
       url: 'http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/collegiate/xml/[YourWord]?key=[YourKeyHere],
       method: "GET"
   }).done(function(response){
       console.log(response);
   });
   ```